# Codeigniter: Load data from controller_1 to view_1 after it has been passed to controller_2

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

This seems simply but can't find an answer. I have a login controller with a data title variable:

```
$data['title'] = 'Login here';
$this->load->view('login/login_view', $data);
```

The view is loaded correctly with the:

```
<title>Login here</title>
```

Cool! 
But when I login using the form and send the data to the "login_verify" controller it checks to see if there is a match or if the fields were populated and if false it returns to the original login view:

```
function index() { 
   $this->load->library('form_validation');

   $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|callback_check_database');

   if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
     //Field validation failed.  User redirected to login page
     $this->load->view('login/login_view');
  } else {
    //Go to private area
    redirect('home', 'refresh');
  }
}
```

How do I get the original $title variable back into the login view if the validation fails? Do I redeclare the original login controller before I load the login view? If so, how? Obviously I don't want to have to redefine the $title variable in the "login_verify" controller.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's really not a way to do it without either re declaring the title variable, or setting a session up. Instead of `$this->load->view('login/login_view')`, why not just redirect back to the login screen `redirect('login')`? Or if you want to get really fancy, you could make that function an ajax function, and pass the form in through javascript instead of having the user reload their page.

On a side note:
You really don't need a separate controller for "login_verify", you can do all of that from the original "login" controller and just make a function called "verify", which you can then get to by navigating to "login/verify". You want your controllers to be broad, but specific to a group of actions.

Comment: Good point. This is day 2 of diving into a new framework and just trying to wrap my head around the MVC. I ended up adding a function in the main controller and then just declaring the variables for the login view at the top of the login.php script

Comment: Haha well Codeigniter is a good one! It's a bit difficult to wrap your head around MVC at first, but you'll learn to love it. Let me know if you have more questions!

Comment: if I use redirect then I lose the validation errors correct?